# Python 2.7 giving unexpected result for read text from webelement to verify if it is numeric

Tags: python, webdriver, unicode-string

I am getting False while using isdigiti() or isnumeric() string method to verify an item value which is numeric string from a web-page [text attribute fetched from a web-element]

1. When I am trying to print it got printed like numeric string.
2. When tried to debug it is showing unicode value.
3. If I assign a variable with same numeric string then it return false if I apply isdigit() or isnumeric() method to this variable.

Code1:

```
value = self.web_page.get_item_value(item_name) # Returns numeric item value from web-page e.g. '1'
print value
if value.isdigit():
     print "Item value is a number"
     pass
else:
     self.fail("Item value is not a number!!")
```

Result1:

```
1
Failure: Item value is not a number!!
```

Code2:

```
new_value = '1' #assigned numeric string to a variable
print new_value
if new_value.isdigit():
     print "Item value is a number"
     pass         
else:
     self.fail("Item value is not a number!!")
```

Result2:

```
1
Item value is a number
```

Comment: `str.isidigt()` returns `True` , if the string is composed of only digits. Your conditions seem to be reversed. I cannot reproduce your second beahvior, are you sure in second you do not have `if not new_value.isdigit():` or so?

Comment: Also try printing `type(value)` in first case

Comment: Edited and corrected the code snippet, thanks for pointing it out.. Question still remains same.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: Type of read value:  <type 'unicode'>

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic backwards.

[`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) returns a boolean; `True` if the string contains only digits, and `False` otherwise, e.g.

```
>>> '1'.isdigit()
True
>>> '1234'.isdigit()
True
>>> '123a'.isdigit()
False
>>> '123 '.isdigit()
False
```

So you should write your `if` statement like this:

```
value = self.web_page.get_item_value(item_name) # Returns numeric item value from web-page e.g. '1'
if value.isdigit():
     print "Item value is a number"
else:
     self.fail("Item value {!r} is not a number!!".format(value))
```

Probably there is some additional whitespace in the string `value`. This will now be displayed in the error message.

If you do find unwanted whitespace, just call `strip()` on it:

```
value = value.strip()
```

and you could add that permanently to your code before calling `isdigit()`.

Comment: Corrected the code in my question above, issue is that when we read text attribute from web-element in a web-page, we get False when try isdigit() on that text as it returns in unicode from web-element

Comment: Change `self.fail("Item value is not a number!!")` to `self.fail("Item value {!r} is not a number!!".format(value))`. Then you will see if there is anything extra in the string, and you'll have a more useful error message too. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: I tried like this:         value = self.web_page.get_item_value(item_name).strip()
        print 'Read item value: ', value
        if not value.isdigit():
            self.fail("Item value {!r} is not a number!!".format(value))                                                                       Result as below:Read item value:  0 AssertionError: Item value u'0' is not a number!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the return value of `self.web_page.get_item_value(item_name)` has some spaces or newlines in it. When the string has space of newlines in it, `isdigit()` returns False.

Example -

```
>>> '1 '.isdigit()
False
>>> '1\n'.isdigit()
False
```

Try stripping the `value` , before doing the `isdigit()` check.

Example -

```
value = self.web_page.get_item_value(item_name).strip()
print value
if value.isdigit():
     print "Item value is a number"
     pass
else:
     self.fail("Item value is not a number!!")
```